# How to loop through worksheets to add a new row with formulae and formatting

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row, userform

I have a series of protected worksheets which are used to collect pupil assessment data. These are locked to prevent users from deleting formulae or causing other issues so I need to be able to add new records to the spreadsheet/database using a userform.

I have compiled the following code using advice from other questions and my (growing) knowledge of VBA, however my knowledge is still rudimentary!

When I try to run the code, I receive an 'Object required' error at the `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select` line, as indicated. I thought that I had defined and indicated the object as `Sh` using the `With Sh` line - is this not the case?

I have included comments in the code to try to explain what I am attempting to achieve. Can anyone shed any light on what I am doing wrong here please?

```
Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()
Dim Sh As Variant
Dim l As Long

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="L1lyL1ly"


    ' IF THERE ARE MORE THAN 103 RECORDS, ADD A NEW ROW AND COPY FORMAT AND FORMULAE

    For Each Sh In Array("Pupil Data", "RWM", "Art", "Computing", "Design Technology", "Geography", "History_", "MFL", "Music", "PE", "RE", "Science", "Bookbands", "KS1 - TRP")

    ' Use the current worksheet
    With Sh

    ' !!!!!!!!!!!! THE ERROR OCCURS ON THE NEXT LINE !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select    ' Find the last used row in the table
        If .Cells(.Rows.Count) < 103 Then GoTo Add_Record            ' If the row number is less than 103 go to the Add_Record section otherwise add a new row and copy all formats and formulae

        .Rows(Selection.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown

        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
            .EntireRow.Copy
            With .Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
                On Error Resume Next
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
                On Error GoTo 0
            End With
        End With
    End With
Next Sh     ' Cycle through to the next worksheet in the array and repeat the 'add line' procedure

Add_Record:   ' COPY NEW CHILD FROM FORM TO SPREADSHEET

Dim LR As Long
    LR = Sheets("Pupil Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set c = Range("A" & LR + 1)

    With Me
        c.Value = .TextBox14.Value
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = .TextBox1.Value
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = .TextBox2.Value
        c.Offset(0, 3).Value = .TextBox3.Value
        c.Offset(0, 4).Value = .TextBox4.Value
        c.Offset(0, 5).Value = .TextBox24.Value
        c.Offset(0, 7).Value = .TextBox25.Value
        c.Offset(0, 8).Value = .TextBox26.Value
        c.Offset(0, 9).Value = .TextBox5.Value
        c.Offset(0, 11).Value = .TextBox27.Value
        c.Offset(0, 12).Value = .TextBox28.Value
        c.Offset(0, 13).Value = .TextBox29.Value
        c.Offset(0, 14).Value = .TextBox30.Value
        c.Offset(0, 15).Value = .TextBox34.Value
        c.Offset(0, 16).Value = .TextBox31.Value
        c.Offset(0, 17).Value = .TextBox32.Value
        c.Offset(0, 18).Value = .TextBox33.Value
        c.Offset(0, 21).Value = .TextBox35.Value
        Call ClearControls
    End With

' FILL EMPTY CHARACTERISTICS CELLS

Dim rCell   As Range, _
        rRng    As Range

    For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.[A4].Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)
        If IsEmpty(rRng) Then GoTo NextRow
        For Each rCell In rRng.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 17)
            If IsEmpty(rCell) Then rCell.Value = "N"
        Next rCell
NextRow:
    Next rRng

' SORT DATA TO INCLUDE NEW CHILD

 Call ResortData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'ActiveSheet.Protect "L1lyL1ly", _                      'Remove the ' from the start of the line when password protected
    'AllowFiltering:=True, _
    'AllowSorting:=True, _
    'AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    'AllowFormattingRows:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: The way you have defined SH, it is just a string value. You might be better off doing `For each SH in Worksheets` and then testing to see if SH.Name is one of the sheets of interest before doing anything to it.

Comment: Thanks StoneGiant. I've gone with a `If Not Sh.Name - "...." solution here. Thank you for the pointer,

Comment: **Side Note:** Using `GoTo` in code outside of `On Error GoTo` is not recommended. (It has been frowned upon by coders for years.) It leads to code that is difficult to follow and maintain. In your example, I would use an `If...Then...Else...End If` construct.

Comment: This is why I love this site! I am definitely not a coder but I am gradually learning! I've used Xabier's code, below, which has removed these aspects but I am now thinking that I need to ensure I build your construct back in!

Answer (score 0):

As commented by StoneGiant, you aren't actually looping through your worksheets, you are also selecting the last row, without first selecting the sheet, which gives you an error, I would also recommend not using nested With statements, not only can it get confusing, it may actually not work as intended, I believe the revised code below will help you achieve what you want:

```
Private Sub cmbAdd_Click()
Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim l As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' IF THERE ARE MORE THAN 103 RECORDS, ADD A NEW ROW AND COPY FORMAT AND FORMULAE

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ' Use the current worksheet
        With Sh
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    ' Find the last used row in the table
            If LastRow < 103 Then GoTo Add_Record            ' If the row number is less than 103 go to the Add_Record section otherwise add a new row and copy all formats and formulae
            .Rows(LastRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Copy
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.ClearContents
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        End With
    Next Sh     ' Cycle through to the next worksheet in the array and repeat the 'add line' procedure

Add_Record:       ' COPY NEW CHILD FROM FORM TO SPREADSHEET

    LR = Sheets("Pupil Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set c = Range("A" & LR + 1)

    With Me
        c.Value = .TextBox14.Value
        c.Offset(0, 1).Value = .TextBox1.Value
        c.Offset(0, 2).Value = .TextBox2.Value
        c.Offset(0, 3).Value = .TextBox3.Value
        c.Offset(0, 4).Value = .TextBox4.Value
        c.Offset(0, 5).Value = .TextBox24.Value
        c.Offset(0, 7).Value = .TextBox25.Value
        c.Offset(0, 8).Value = .TextBox26.Value
        c.Offset(0, 9).Value = .TextBox5.Value
        c.Offset(0, 11).Value = .TextBox27.Value
        c.Offset(0, 12).Value = .TextBox28.Value
        c.Offset(0, 13).Value = .TextBox29.Value
        c.Offset(0, 14).Value = .TextBox30.Value
        c.Offset(0, 15).Value = .TextBox34.Value
        c.Offset(0, 16).Value = .TextBox31.Value
        c.Offset(0, 17).Value = .TextBox32.Value
        c.Offset(0, 18).Value = .TextBox33.Value
        c.Offset(0, 21).Value = .TextBox35.Value
        Call ClearControls
    End With

' FILL EMPTY CHARACTERISTICS CELLS

Dim rCell As Range, rRng As Range

    For Each rRng In ActiveSheet.[A4].Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 2)
        If IsEmpty(rRng) Then GoTo NextRow
        For Each rCell In rRng.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 17)
            If IsEmpty(rCell) Then rCell.Value = "N"
        Next rCell
NextRow:
    Next rRng

' SORT DATA TO INCLUDE NEW CHILD

 Call ResortData

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Xabier - this has definitely moved me on. I have now got a 'Method or data member not found' error on the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents` line. Am I right in thinking that this line deletes any contents in the new row that has been copied from the row above?

Comment: @gbra to be honest I wasn't sure what you where trying to do there, but I've now updated my answer to clear the contents of that row before adding the formulas, hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks Xabier. Sorry to be a pain in the @$$ but I'm now getting a 'Next without For' error at the `Next Sh` line. This is clearly my VBA ignorance but I thought that with the `For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheet` line, this was the `For` that it would link with?

Comment: @gbra Yes you are correct, the Next Sh is for the For Each Sh in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets, I was testing this and I didn't get any such error, can you double check that you copied the code properly? Sometimes you can get this error when you don't specify and End If, but that is not the case here, so I'm unsure...